# Windows 10 bootloader not working

Tags: windows-10

I recently uninstalled ubuntu from my dual boot system and since then whenever I start my system

```
System BootOrder not found. Initializing defaults.
Reset System
```

appears. Can anyone help?
This keep repeating every 3-4 seconds. I can access boot menu and then windows 10 starts but why I can't simply go to windows 10?

Comment: What is the computer? Please add photos of your BIOS and especially of boot order and Security settings.

Comment: What do you mean by computer? It's HP 15r-014tx i5 laptop. boot order is showing nothing but OS boot manager and efi. and what I did not understand what do you mean by security settings

Comment: Can you get into the BIOS? Most often this is done by pressing F2 during the boot. While in the BIOS, you will find somewhere the boot order, and you might have a section named something like Security, depending on the BIOS version.

Comment: Check this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042747/system-bootorder-not-found).

Comment: Boot to WinPE/WinRE and do the following: **If UEFI:** this likely occurred from Ubuntu modifying or removing the EFI partition. To recreate, see Steps 3 and 5 at the end of [this](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800) answer; **If BIOS:** `BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /FixBoot && BootRec /RebuildBCD`

Answer (score 0):

When you delete or otherwise uninstall Ubuntu from a Windows 10 system the Grub bootloader remains.  You need to get rid of it by using a repair disk to get to the command prompt, and type

> bootrec.exe /fixmbr

Restart and you should be good.  A detailed write up with pics can be found at [Uninstall Linux dual-boot](https://www.howtogeek.com/141818/how-to-uninstall-a-linux-dual-boot-system-from-your-computer/)

Comment: Your solution did not work.

Comment: When you say it didn't work, did you still get an "operation completed successfully" message in the cmd prompt, but it still failed to boot afterwards?

Comment: yes, that's what i meant

Comment: This answer is missing the two additional `BootRec` commands required.

Answer (score 0):

This likely occurred due to modifying/removing the boot partition during the removal of Ubuntu:

1. **Boot to [WinPE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-intro)/[WinRE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-recovery-environment--windows-re--technical-reference)** 
    <sup>*(Windows install USB: once GUI loads, `Shift`+`F10` to access terminal)*</sup>
2. **Select the OS drive:** <sup>*([`DiskPart`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart))*</sup>

   ```bash
   DiskPart

     Lis Dis
     Sel Dis #
   ```

   1. **Create boot partition:** *(if boot partition exists, go to *Step 3*, else create it)* 
      **BIOS:**

      ```bash
      ::# List partitions and select the OS partition:
          Lis Vol
          Sel Vol #

      ::# Partition should be 100MB formwatted:
          Shrink desired=130 minimum=130

      Cre Par Pri Size=128
      Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label=Boot
      Active
      ```

      **UEFI:**

      ```bash
      ::# List partitions and select the OS partition:
          Lis Vol
          Sel Vol #

      ::# Formatted size: EFI: 260MB | MSR: 128MB
          Shrink desired=400 minimum=400

      Cre Par EFI Size=100
      Format Quick Fs=FAT32 Label=EFI
      Assign Letter=Y
      Cre Par Msr Size=16
      ```
3. **[Resolve](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-bootrec-exe-in-the-windows-re-to-troubleshoot-startup-issues-902ebb04-daa3-4f90-579f-0fbf51f7dd5d) any boot issues:** 
    **BIOS:**

   ```bash
   BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /FixBoot && BootRec /RebuildBCD
   ```

   **UEFI:**

   ```bash
   ::# With existing bootable EFI partition:
       BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD


   ::# Without existing bootable EFI partition:
       ::# Create EFI directories and enter:
           MkDir "Y:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot"
           Cd /d "Y:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot"

       ::# Create EFI boot structure:
           BootRec /Fixboot

           ::# If Access Denied error occurs (C: is OS partition):
               BcdBoot C:\Windows /s C: /f UEFI

       ::# Resolve any other boot issues:
           BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD
   ```
4. **Remove EFI mountpoint *(if applicable)* → Reboot:** `wpeutil reboot`

   ```bash
   DiskPart

     Sel Vol Y
     Remove
     Exit
   ```